# Mock API Responses on Android

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2

I am creating an android app that requires an api call, the api is still in development, but I want to create a dummy retrofit api request that will return an actual json value as response so I can speed up the app development. But now I don't know how to go about it, I have searched online for answers but I don't seems to understand any.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

Using Retrofit/Okhttp mock, you can place the json file in the assets folder and configure retrofit mock/ okhttp mock to serve the json file as the response, when a particular endpoint is hit.

1. Retrofit Mock [Runs within your app]
   https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock
2. OKHttp Mock [Runs within your app]
   https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver
3. Json-server [Runs on your PC/Mac]
   https://github.com/typicode/json-server